# ZK Radiogroup returns incorrect getSelectedIndex()

Tags: java, zk

I am using ZK 8.5.2.1 and I have popup window with `Radiogroup`. The `zul`:

```
<zk xmlns="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul http://www.zkoss.org/2005/zul/zul.xsd">
    <popup use="com.myproject.webapp.docbrowse.filter.FiltrationModePopup" width="330px">
            <vlayout sclass="content">
                <hlayout>
                    <label sclass="title" value="List form setup"/>
                </hlayout>
                <radiogroup id="rgScrollerMode" sclass="scrollermode-radio">
                    <grid>
                        <rows>
                            <row sclass="radio-border">
                                <radio label="Standart"/>
                            </row>
                            <row sclass="radio-border">
                                <radio label="Archive / Select year"/>
                                <hlayout id="archivePanel" use="com.myproject.webapp.docbrowse.ArchivePanel"/>
                            </row>
                            <row sclass="radio-border">
                                <radio label="Trash"/>
                            </row>
                        </rows>
                    </grid>
                </radiogroup>
        . . .
                <div align="right">
                    <button id="okButton" label="Accept" sclass="acceptButton"/>
                    <button id="cancelButton" label="Cancel" sclass="cancelButton"/>
                </div>
            </vlayout>
    </popup>
</zk>
```

Class `FiltrationModePopup`:

```
public class FiltrationModePopup extends Popup implements AfterCompose, IdSpace {
    public static final String STANDARD_MODE = "/icons/toolbar/table_mode.png";
    private static final String ARCHIVE_MODE = "/icons/toolbar/archive_mode.png";
    private static final String RECYCLEBIN_MODE = "/icons/toolbar/recycle_mode.png";
    private Radiogroup rgScrollerMode;
    //. . . other properties

    @Override
    public void afterCompose() {
        . . .
        rgScrollerMode = (Radiogroup) getFellow("rgScrollerMode");
        final Button okButton = (Button) getFellow("okButton");
        okButton.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new SerializableEventListener<Event>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(Event event) {
                filtrationModeSaver.save(FiltrationModePopup.this);
                final FiltrationSettings filtrationSettings = createFiltrationSettingsFromPopup();
                EventUtils.postEvent(new FiltersChangeEvent(FiltrationModePopup.this, filtrationSettings));
                EventUtils.postEvent(new RefreshScrollerEvent(FiltrationModePopup.this));

                close();
            }
        });
        addForward(Events.ON_OK, okButton, Events.ON_CLICK);
        EventUtils.registerHandler(this);
    }

    private FiltrationSettings createFiltrationSettingsFromPopup() {
        return new FiltrationSettings(getScrollerMode(), getArchiveValue());
    }

    public ScrollerMode getScrollerMode() {
        switch (rgScrollerMode.getSelectedIndex()) {
            case 1:
                return ScrollerMode.ARCHIVE;
            case 2:
                return ScrollerMode.RECYCLEBIN;
            default:
                return ScrollerMode.STANDARD;
        }
    }
    // . . . Other code
}
```

So, when popup displays on screen and I selecting some Radio item and pressing "Accept" button - selectedIndex is not always correct. Sometimes it's -1, sometimes it's old selected value and sometimes it's correct. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplify your code, and it always get the correct selected index.

```
    public class FiltrationModePopup extends Popup implements AfterCompose, IdSpace {
        private Radiogroup rgScrollerMode;

        @Override
        public void afterCompose() {
            rgScrollerMode = (Radiogroup) getFellow("rgScrollerMode");
            final Button okButton = (Button) getFellow("okButton");
            okButton.addEventListener(Events.ON_CLICK, new SerializableEventListener<Event>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(Event event) {
                    System.out.println(rgScrollerMode.getSelectedIndex());
                    close();
                }
            });
            addForward(Events.ON_OK, okButton, Events.ON_CLICK);
        }
    }
```

You need to trace what happens before you call `getSelectedIndex()`. You can comment out codes inside onClick listener and gradually add codes line by line to find out the root cause.

Comment: I cached `scrollerMode`, cause, I am agree, that it called to often. After than, I made `EventListener` for `OnCheck` event of `RadioGroup`. Seems work better, but not always. Anyway, thanks a lot!